# Could I use case statement not in query but ONLY in group by()?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

Can I use case statement only in Group by()?

For example, I need to group results of my calculation by groups of incom level.

```
user_id   income
1          10
2          20
3          100
4          500
```

I want to get result:

```
 number_of_users  income
  1               <10
  2               10 - 150
  1               >150
```

Could I use case statement not in query but ONLY in group by()?

Comment: You will need it in your SELECT portion in order to get that output `10 - 150`, `<10`, and `>150`. And that will need to be in your GROUP BY as well.

Comment: @JNevill so is it necessary to use case both times?

Comment: It is to get the output that you want. The server won't know to write `10-150` or `<10`. You have to tell it how to write that in your output and the ONLY place you can affect that is in the SELECT portion of the statement.

Comment: @JNevill  what about usung HAVING instead of CASE in GROUP?

Comment: It still won't affect the actual literal output of `10-150` or `<10` or `>150`. If you must have those in your output the only way that is going to happen is if it's in your SELECT. Your FROM, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY, LIMIT, WINDOW, INTO, and FOR clauses can't affect which columns are outputted and what is written in those columns. You can head over to sqlfiddle.com and create your test table and test this.

Comment: @JNevill, thanks. Could U explain, can i use "case when (select sum(income))<10 then '0-10' ". It is a litle bit another question...Is it right syntax?

Comment: BTW, that's a case _expression_, not _statement_. (It returns a value!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN income < 10 THEN '<10'
              WHEN income <= 150 THEN '10-150'
              ELSE '> 150'
         END AS income, COUNT(*) AS num_of_users
FROM tab
GROUP BY CASE WHEN income < 10 THEN '<10'
              WHEN income <= 150 THEN '10-150'
              ELSE '> 150'
         END
```

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков You could but you will get strange incorrect output (or an error if you are on mysql 5.7 or newer and haven't toggled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY off). Why don't you run the SQL and give it a whirl?

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @Lukasz' answer.

```
select income, COUNT(*) AS num_of_users
from
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN income < 10 THEN '<10'
                WHEN income <= 150 THEN '10-150'
                ELSE '> 150'
           END AS income
    FROM tab
) dt
group by income
```

Using a derived table to

- Save some typing
- Avoid silly errors caused by different case expressions in the select list and the group by clause
- Be ANSI SQL compliant.